# Как в яндекс картах менять иконку кластера, в зависимости от типа меток?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У меня на яндекс карте, есть метки обычных магазинов и круглосуточных магазинов.

Если в элемент кластера попали только обычные магазины, то мне нужно отображать одну иконку, а если в элемент кластера, помимо обычных меток магазина, попала метка круглосуточного магазина, то мне нужно отображать этот кластер с другой иконкой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

*Т.е. как работать с кластером я разобрался, а как сделать, что бы он, в зависимости от попавших в него магазинов, отображал разную иконку, пока так и не понял*

Comment: ```if (shop.type === 'default) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: @Alexander Chernykh, я хорошо знаком с конструкциями ветвления в JavaScript и не только:), проблема не в этом, а в том, как эту логику прокинуть в API яндекс карт для кластера:)

Answer (score 0):

Можно выстроить логику кластеризации на сервере с помощью [RemoteObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about.html).